Change the language of a LaTex template
I'm having trouble with a LaTex template I downloaded from the MIT website (https://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/). This template has some predefined terms in English that I would like to translate into Spanish, for example "by" above the Author name. I tried some solutions recommended by ChatGPT (use
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}

etc.) and TexMaker compiles correctly but the language reminds the same. Does anyone know how to change the languge or rewrite this terms? Thanks for your time in advance.


welcome! don't ask chatgpt for latex code - it produces terrible code because there's a great deal of bad code around proportionately and that's what it has trained on. please provide a small minimal working example we can compile to reproduce the issue. as a general rule: don't use a template. especially don't use a template which doesn't respond to standard methods for producing language-appropriate output. especially don't do that if you need a language which differs from whatever it uses. really, if this is a problem, there will be many others. extricate yourself while you can ;).

to whoever downvoted and whoever voted to close: please don't downvote or vote to close questions without leaving any kind of comment. especially, please don't do this for new users. how exactly is the OP supposed to figure out what's wrong with the question if nobody says anything? far better to explain than downvote/vote to close anyway, but voting without also explaining is just mean.

Please, add a MWE (minimal working example) with what you have attempted so far, so that we can do some tests. And, please, DON'T ASK CHATGPT! (Sorry for the shout, but it’s very frustrating the damage AI chats can be doing to the LaTeX  world.)

All English terms are written directly into the mitthesis.cls file, so you can only change them to another language by modifying the cls file.

Did you follow the babel hint on p. 8 "if you use multiple languages, load babel in a
fontset file before loading fonts" ? https://ctan.org/pkg/mitthesis

The template or class has a very precisely specified purpose. The creators therefore saw no need to give it the flexibility of a universal class like the standard classes, the KOMA-Script classes, memoir or many other classes freely available on CTAN. The standard recommendation is therefore to use it exclusively for the specified purpose, as adaptations are usually only possible with a great deal of effort and by modifying a copy of the class.

The "by" seems to be hard-coded in line 539 of the template. Other things are also hard coded. So, you would need to make a copy of the template under another name and edit that for all occurrences of English terms, but then it would be another template. (And I did not even check for a copyright notice.)

In this specific case, as suggested before, you have to modify the class file "mitthesis.cls", lines 499 and 539. Replace the word "by" with something else (e.g. "von" in German). Likewise, lines 731 and 759 ("Submitted\ to\ the\ "). Use search & replace of your editor to adjust for more as appropriate. Adding the \usepackage[yourlanguage]{babel} statement in line 26 of file "MIT-Thesis.tex" seems to be enough already to adapt the language of sections header etc. However, overall, it seems doubtful to me whether the course of action is right in your case? As the creator suggests, the template supports theses or dissertations formatted according to the requirements of MIT only, and maybe your thesis is for another university? If so, I would start with a different template.

That worked! I was able to replace the predefined terms and change the language for most of the titles, with \usepackage[spanish, mexico]{babel} (Colombia is not there but the spanish from my neighbours is almost the same). Other sections required to modify the chapter’s title in every class file (e.g. \chapter{Introducción}). You’re right, I chose this template because I think the layout is perfect for my thesis and is similar to older theses in my university’s repository. Thank you very much, everyone helped me a lot!
